# OneDrive subscription and Office 365

Tags: onedrive, office365

I bought a 100GB OneDrive subscription last year and used about 70% of the space. A couple of months ago I bought an Office 365 subscription that comes with 1TB of OneDrive storage.

I still have over 1TB available.

I expect that if I allow the 100GB OneDrive subscription to expire and keep the Office 365 subscription current I will keep all my data but have 100GB fewer free space.
Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on a few things.  What SKU or version of office 365 did you purchase, and did you link it to your existing microsoft account.

If you bought the O365 personal - and used the same Microsoft account that you linked to the 100GB subscription, than this should all be pooled storage. That means you should see that you have the 1TB + 100GB in the same subscription.  If that's the case you can let the 100GB subscription expire and just keep the O365 subscription and your data will be fine (but 100 GB less).

If however - you used different accounts,  your OneDrive is not linked and you need to transfer your files before letting your subscription expire (there is a grace period for accessing your files, but don't leave it to chance).  Additionally if you purchased a business subscription instead of personal - then the OneDrive service is completely separate as well (there are actually to products), and again you have to transfer the data.